# Install a Github App on an Org through API

Tags: github

Is there a way to install a Github app on an Organization through the API?

I am able to add a repo if the Github App is already installed through this API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/installations#add-a-repository-to-an-app-installation
but I wanted to automate the addition of the App as well